# Order of events with and

Tags: grammar

If I say "Purge the steam wand and wipe it with a cloth". Am I purging the wand while I wipe it? Can it mean the same as "Purge the steam wand and then wipe it with a cloth"?

Comment: While "Purge the steam wand and wipe it with a cloth" would make sense to most people, the OP is quite right that it doesn't make it clear that these are sequential steps and, in this age where we have to print "contents may be hot" on a coffee cup or "contains nuts" on a bag of peanuts, it's simply not safe to assume that the reader knows what you mean. The second option makes that clear.

Comment: After posting that last comment, I'm wondering about calling to close this one as, while I'm sure it was asked as an English usage question. I'm worried that it's a bit close to legal advice because of the litigation risk of getting it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> Purge the steam wand and wipe it with a cloth.

This can mean three different things:

> **Purge** the steam wand and **then** **wipe** it with a cloth.
>
> **Purge** the steam wand while **wiping** it with a cloth.
>
> **Wipe** the steam wand with a cloth  and **then** **purge** it .

The word **and** only tells that both actions must be done, it does not prescribe any order.  Most people would probably infer that they are sequential events, **purge** **then, wipe**, however, if it is important that **purge** is done before **wipe**, then you should explicitly state

> **Purge** the steam wand and **then** **wipe** it with a cloth.